# Modify requestvalidation in WebAPI (Azure)

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

We have a Asp.NET web api that handles requests from Android and iOS apps. We started to experience issues with GET requests that contained query strings. A URL like this: http://localhost:10723/api/Locations?userId=32432-a4r2-f32r3 gave this response:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)

After some debugging I saw that the querystring had been encoded, so the actual request was http://localhost:10723/api/Locations%3FuserId=32432-a4r2-f32r3, and that caused the issue. I can make changes to the apps that will fix this, but since this a app that is in production right now, I am desperately looking for a quick fix in the API that will allow the apps to work now.

What I have tried so far:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

And related httpRuntime web.config tricks.

I have also written a custom request validator.

But everything is telling me that this is something that happens before the pagevalidation and my request validator is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a rewrite rule for url on the server:

```
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Allowing querystrings.">
        <match url="^(.*)\?(.*)$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?{R:2}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```